# Rのエラー「 引数に異なる列数のデータフレームが含まれています」について

Tags: r

R上で以下のようなエラーが出て先に進むことができません。
分かる方がいらっしゃれば教えてください。

```
macro2Ans<-data.frame(macro2$ym,macro2$time_id,macro2$sociotropic_bd,macro2$sociotropic_gd,macro2$liv_gd,
+                      macro2$liv_bd,macro2$approve,macro2$dis,macro2$cpi,macro2$unemp,macro2$ruling,
+                      macro2$nav_ini,macro2$slap,macro2$corruption,macro2$synthesis)
Error in data.frame(macro2$ym, macro2$time_id, macro2$sociotropic_bd,  : 
   引数に異なる列数のデータフレームが含まれています: 698, 0 
macro2Ans<-na.omit(macro2Ans)
```

Comment: rulingがcsvファイルに入ってなくてエラーがでていたことが判明しました。cubickさん、ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

変数の名前を間違っているのが理由かと思います。
`macro2$xxxxx`の`xxxxx`の部分、どれかが間違っていませんか？
正しい名前は `names(macro2)` で確認できるので、一致しない部分がないか確認してみてください。